# Solutions for (N,K)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What techniques can I use to find solutions (N,K) of this diophantine equation,
$$   56+63N=11K.$$

(I think it has something to do with congruence ? ) Can a solution be obtained where N And K are natural numbers?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  There is an expectation here that when you pose a question that you state its source, show any work you have done on the problem, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive a response that is appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: Must N and K be  positive integers?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig,I'm very bad in Math,and this question is my Home work

Comment: @Bernard yes N and K are positive integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have
$$1+8N\equiv 0\iff  8N\equiv 10\iff N\equiv 4\pmod{11},$$
we have
$$(N,K)=(11m+4,63m+28).$$

Comment: so it has infinitely many solutions :D

Comment: @GeaBirsh: Yes, it has.

Comment: @GeaBirsh: Note that $m\ge 0\in\mathbb Z$ if $N,K$ are positive integers.

Comment: Yes thanks @mathlove